# an error while yum install from local repository on CentOS 8

Tags: linux, server, centos, yum, system-administration

looks like it has issue to find the files but i checked and its there! i tried just any thing to install and i get the same error for every file,i just have to install from local repository because its a server within an offline environment .

ok so i get the following error:

```
[root@Nagios-01 yum.repos.d]# yum install php
Last metadata expiration check: 0:19:00 ago on Thu 09 Dec 2021 10:29:52 AM IST.
Dependencies resolved.
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                  Architecture                                 Version                                                                         Repository                                       Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php                                                      x86_64                                       7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5                                            appstream                                       1.5 M
Installing dependencies:
 centos-logos-httpd                                       noarch                                       85.8-2.el8                                                                      baseos                                           75 k
 httpd                                                    x86_64                                       2.4.37-41.module_el8.5.0+977+5653bbea                                           appstream                                       1.4 M
 mod_http2                                                x86_64                                       1.15.7-3.module_el8.4.0+778+c970deab                                            appstream                                       154 k
 nginx-filesystem                                         noarch                                       1:1.20.0-2.module_el8.5.0+899+43b718f6                                          appstream                                        25 k
 php-common                                               x86_64                                       7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5                                            appstream                                       702 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 php-cli                                                  x86_64                                       7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5                                            appstream                                       3.1 M
 php-fpm                                                  x86_64                                       7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5                                            appstream                                       1.6 M
 php-json                                                 x86_64                                       7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5                                            appstream                                        74 k
 php-mbstring                                             x86_64                                       7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5                                            appstream                                       484 k
 php-opcache                                              x86_64                                       7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5                                            appstream                                       267 k
 php-pdo                                                  x86_64                                       7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5                                            appstream                                       123 k
 php-xml                                                  x86_64                                       7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5                                            appstream                                       174 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  13 Packages

Total download size: 9.6 M
Installed size: 37 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/httpd-2.4.37-41.module_el8.5.0+977+5653bbea.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "httpd-2.4.37-41.module_el8.5.0+977+5653bbea.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/mod_http2-1.15.7-3.module_el8.4.0+778+c970deab.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "mod_http2-1.15.7-3.module_el8.4.0+778+c970deab.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/nginx-filesystem-1.20.0-2.module_el8.5.0+899+43b718f6.noarch.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "nginx-filesystem-1:1.20.0-2.module_el8.5.0+899+43b718f6.noarch" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/php-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "php-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/php-cli-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "php-cli-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/php-common-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "php-common-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/php-fpm-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "php-fpm-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/php-json-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "php-json-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/php-mbstring-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "php-mbstring-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/php-opcache-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "php-opcache-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/php-pdo-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "php-pdo-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/appstream/Packages/php-xml-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "php-xml-7.4.19-1.module_el8.5.0+815+1c4fd2e5.x86_64" from local repository "appstream" has incorrect checksum
Error opening localhost/root/Repository/baseos/Packages/centos-logos-httpd-85.8-2.el8.noarch.rpm: No such file or directory
Package "centos-logos-httpd-85.8-2.el8.noarch" from local repository "baseos" has incorrect checksum
Error: Some packages from local repository have incorrect checksum
[root@Nagios-01 yum.repos.d]#
```

my .repo files look like this:

```
[extras]

name=CentOS Linux $releasever - Extras
baseurl="file://localhost/root/Repository/extras"
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: No such file or directory

You may have used wrong baseurl, you can try

```
[extras]

name=CentOS Linux $releasever - Extras
baseurl="file:///root/Repository/extras"
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial
```